# UIScrollView Paging Inset next page

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

How do you create a UIScrollView with pages that inset the next page?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMDUW.png

My Current code as follows:

```
class scrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let V1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeToCategory") as UIViewController!
        self.addChildViewController(V1!)
        self.scrollView.addSubview((V1?.view)!)
        V1?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V1?.view.frame = scrollView.bounds

        let V2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeatureViewController") as UIViewController!
        self.addChildViewController(V2!)
        self.scrollView.addSubview((V2?.view)!)
        V2?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V2?.view.frame = scrollView.bounds

        var V2Frame: CGRect = V2!.view.frame
        V2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
        V2?.view.frame = V2Frame

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:(self.view.frame.width) * 2, height: (self.view.frame.height))
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: (self.view.frame.width) * 1, y: (self.view.frame.height))
    }
}
```